# How to get public URL after uploading image to S3?

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm developing a C# application in which I make some uploads to AWS S3 service. I'm reading the docs and I can't find where to get the public URL after a upload. Here's my code:

```
    public void AddFile(Stream image, string key)
    {          
            var uploadRequest = new TransferUtilityUploadRequest();
            uploadRequest.CannedACL = S3CannedACL.PublicRead;
            uploadRequest.InputStream = image;
            uploadRequest.BucketName = _bucket;
            uploadRequest.Key = key;

            using (TransferUtility fileTransferUtility = new TransferUtility(_client))
            {                 
                fileTransferUtility.Upload(uploadRequest);
            }            
    }
```

As you can see I put the access to file as public with **S3CannedACL.PublicRead**. So it will act like a CDN, I know that amazon has the CloudFront service for CDN servers but I must use the S3 regular bucket.

I want to know if its possible to get the fixed URL after the upload method. I just can see on the tutorials and documentation to get the "`PreSignedUrl`" with expire time, but I don't want expire time, I need to save this URL on the database.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Your application should be using some configuration/properties file, where the name of the bucket is stored for later reference.  Use, for example, a properties file with a properties defined like this:

```
application.bucket=mybucket-example-com
```

Use this value both when referencing the bucket in your app (eg replace `_bucket` with `application.bucket` in your code), **and** when you want to express or return the public URL.

If your app has uploaded a file to the key `userid/images/test.jpg`, then the public URL can be expressed as:

```
https://[application.bucket].s3.amazonaws.com/[key]
```

This will resolve to the public URL of

`https://mybucket-example-com.s3.amazonaws.com/userid/images/test.jpg`

The nice thing about this approach is that in your testing environment, you can have a different bucket specified in your test configuration.

In testing, you may want to use `application.bucket=test-mybucket-example-com`.

This way your code would not require any changes in this regard when switching between production and testing environments.

Comment: Note: Buckets created in Regions launched after March 20, 2019 are not reachable via the https://bucket.s3.amazonaws.com naming scheme.

Answer (score 5):

You could actually build this url based on the bucket name and the path where you uploaded the file. See this [doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/access-bucket-intro.html) about accessing a bucket, where it describes the url format.

e.g:

```
https://bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/path/to/your/file
https://bucket.s3-aws-region.amazonaws.com/path/to/your/file
https://s3-aws-region.amazonaws.com/bucket/path/to/your/file
```

Please note that your file must be public, otherwise you will get a permission denied.

**Note**: the path-style (`https://s3-aws-region.amazonaws.com/bucket/path/to/your/file` is now deprecated and should not be used anymore

Answer (score 0):

Not sure on the exact command in C#, but in java you can use getResourceUrl() to get the uploaded file url. something similar will also be available in C#.

Below method uploads file in a particular folder in a bucket and return the generated url of the file uploaded.

```java
private String uploadFileToS3Bucket(final String bucketName, final File file) {
    final String uniqueFileName = uploadFolder + "/" + file.getName();
    LOGGER.info("Uploading file with name= " + uniqueFileName);
    final PutObjectRequest putObjectRequest = new PutObjectRequest(bucketName, uniqueFileName, file);
    PutObjectResult putObjectResult = amazonS3.putObject(putObjectRequest);
    return ((AmazonS3Client) amazonS3).getResourceUrl(bucketName, uniqueFileName);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As Baig commented, Rodrigo's answer is now outdated.

As per the documentation (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/access-bucket-intro.html), the public URL is now formed like this:
`https://bucket-name.s3.Region.amazonaws.com/key-name`